# create a contact with firstname and lastname

Tags: exchangewebservices

I've run this simple request to create a contact :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
    <soap:Header>
        <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013"/>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <m:CreateItem>
            <m:Items>
                <t:Contact>
                    <t:DisplayName>test9</t:DisplayName>
                    <t:FirstName>firstname</t:FirstName>
                    <t:LastName>lastname</t:LastName>
                    <t:FullName>test9</t:FullName>
                    <t:Categories></t:Categories>
                    <t:EmailAddresses></t:EmailAddresses>
                    <t:PhysicalAddresses></t:PhysicalAddresses>
                    <t:PhoneNumbers></t:PhoneNumbers>
                    <t:ImAddresses></t:ImAddresses>
                </t:Contact>
            </m:Items>
        </m:CreateItem>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

the server answer is correct and the contact is successfully created but without a firstname and without a lastname.

I expect the contact to be created with a firstname and a lastname. What's wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

The XML elements in a Contact for FirstName is GivenName https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/givenname and for LastName it's Surname https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/surname so your Request should be

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
    <soap:Header>
        <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013"/>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <m:CreateItem>
            <m:Items>
                <t:Contact>
                    <t:DisplayName>test9</t:DisplayName>
                    <t:GivenName>firstname</t:GivenName>
                    <t:Surname>lastname</t:Surname>
                    <t:FullName>test9</t:FullName>
                    <t:Categories></t:Categories>
                    <t:EmailAddresses></t:EmailAddresses>
                    <t:PhysicalAddresses></t:PhysicalAddresses>
                    <t:PhoneNumbers></t:PhoneNumbers>
                    <t:ImAddresses></t:ImAddresses>
                </t:Contact>
            </m:Items>
        </m:CreateItem>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer which solves... only the firstname issue :(... this request does not create a contact with a lastname

Comment: (and if we want perfection, the displayname is not correctly set too)

Comment: Casing is important in EWS I didn't look at the doco correctly so I cased surname like givename which is incorrect for whatever reason they have done GivenName and Surname. You should also really be setting the FileAs property also